# MySql doesn't return anything

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication, return

I'm just messing around with PHP and MySql to learn things... Untill now everything worked out fine, but now I just can't find any solution.
The base is a very simple login system. Now i was trying to read username and password from a database called 'login' with the table 'userTBL' and fields 'username' and 'password'.

```
 <?php 
    session_start();

    mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die('NO MYSQL CONNECTION!');
    mysql_select_db('login');  

    if ($_GET['login']) {
        $username = ($_POST['username']);
        $password = ($_POST['password']);

        $tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user`");

        $data = mysql_fetch_array($tmp);

        if($tmp) {
            echo 'FULL<br />';
        } else {
            echo 'EMPTY<br />';
        }

        $_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $data['password'];

         if ($username == $_SESSION['username'] && $password == $_SESSION['password']) {
             $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
             header("Location: protected.php");
             exit;
         } else echo "Wrong details!<br />";
    }
    if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
        header("Location: protected.php"); 
    }
?>
```

It seems like the database would not return anything, but why?!?!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check for errors with `mysql_error()`

Comment: How does it "seem" like the database does not return anything? Also, `mysql_query()` returns a resource for `SELECT` queries; if there is no error in the query, `$tmp` will always be true, even for zero returned rows. Also, do not use the `mysql` extension as it is deprecated and its use is discouraged.

Comment: You say the table name is `userTBL` but have `"SELECT * FROM user"`

Comment: - mysql_error() displays any error message...
- It seems it doesn't return anything, because $tmp array is emty

Comment: `$tmp` is not an array, it is a result resource. Your data will be in `$data`.

Comment: I'm so blind... Thanks Musa, that's the mistake I made...
Sorry for bothering... My fault..

Comment: If you select all rows from the table (users table probably would fit more than one user) then you must loop thriugh these rows. Also your $data array is never used after fetching...

Comment: It should not be a problem if usernames are unique, right? Of course it's used -> $_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'];
EDIT: I deleted the WHERE `username` = '$username' etc. during troubleshooting

Comment: Please don't build new applications with the deprecated `mysql_query` interface. Using `mysqli` or PDO is the recommended way and ends up being easier to use properly. You should never insert unescaped data into your SQL. Always use [proper SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that your table is called 'userTBL' but you're querying the table 'user'. Change your query to this: $tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `userTBL` WHERE username = {$username} AND password = {$password}");
The 'WHERE' clause will ensure that the query only returns data matching the username and password that was typed into the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
    session_start();

    mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die('NO MYSQL CONNECTION!');
    mysql_select_db('login');  

    if ($_GET['login']) {
        $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);

        $tmp = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `userTBL` WHERE `user` = "'.$username.'"');

        while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($tmp))
        {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $data['password'];

         if ($password == $_SESSION['password']) {
             $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
             header("Location: protected.php");
             exit;
         } else echo "Wrong details!<br />";
         }
    }
    if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
        header("Location: protected.php"); 
    }
?>
```

Also: use salt+hash to store passwords in database.